# Every Element of Order 2 is in the Center of a Group

Tags: group-theory

I'm taking an introductory group theory class, and one of the problems I was assigned is to show that if an element $g \in G$ has order $2$, then $g \in Z(G)$, where $Z(G)$ is the center of G.  Can anyone help me out on this one?  I'm a little stuck.

Comment: This isn't true, can you give more context?

Comment: See: [prove that if a group contains exactly one element of order 2, then that element is in the center.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821309/prove-that-if-a-group-contains-exactly-one-element-of-order-2-then-that-element?rq=1)

Comment: This is only true in a group with one and only one element of order 2.  See the link above.

Comment: This is clearly false, take $G=S_3$, then elements is order 2 are the transpositions, while $Z(G)$ is trivial. Didn't you miss some important assumptions on $G$?

Comment: "In every group G in which one and only one element $x\in G$ has order 2, $x\in Z(G)$